# Python: inheretance messes up order of arguments for __eq__

Tags: python

For some I-dont-care-about reason python swaps order of at least `__eq__` and `__ne__` when it sees that one side is an instance of derived class of the other side

```
    class Base:
        def __init__(self,n):
            self.whoami=n
        def __eq__(self, other):
            print(f"{self.whoami} == {other.whoami}")
        
    class Derived(Base):
        pass

    base_lhs = Base("base.lhs")
    base_rhs = Base("base.rhs")
    derived_rhs = Derived("derived.rhs")

    ok                              = base_lhs == base_rhs
    what_the_fuck_you_stupid_donkey = base_lhs == derived_rhs
```

Produces

```
base.lhs == base.rhs
derived.rhs == base.lhs
```

What's a good way to make python stop doing this implicit swap of arguments? Can I inside of `__eq__` somehow check that python done goofed and I need to rearrange arguments back? I can't  simply swap them or return NotImplemented as sometimes I compare base to derived and sometimes I do it the other way.

Comment: Sorry not an answer but is probably relevant info. The last paragraph of [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) explains that this seems to be expected behaviour `If the operands are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority `

Comment: Python's `==` operator is supposed to be its own reflection in that it produces the same result whatever the order of the arguments. If you want to give different results depending on the order of the arguments, then you are not using the operator for its intended purpose and you would probably be better off just writing a method to do it.

Comment: The quoted rule makes sense. The more specialized `__eq__` wins.